# Detecting error in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, nouns

There was a sentence and I had to detect the error in it.
The sentence read:

> Entrance exams for the posts of associate professors will begin from Tuesday.

The answer was:

> instead of *posts*, *post* is correct.

But I don't think it is correct. There may be many posts of many professors so one can easily say posts/post of professors.
 But is that correct what I think?

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing the sentence, my first correction would be to change ***from*** *Tuesday* to ***on*** *Tuesday*. I find that the use of *from* to be a lot more unnatural than the plural *posts*.

Having said that, while the plural *posts* is possible, it doesn't sound as natural to me as the singular would.

However, even though there might be a plural number of *posts*, they will still all be for an *associate professor* position. So, the singular *professor* does need to be used. Turning both of them into a plural is a mistake.

In short, I would write it like this:

> Entrance exams for the post of associate **professor** will begin **on** Tuesday.

While my preference is for the singular, I would be fine with the plural *posts* if there really were several posts available.

---

If there are several posts available, you can look at the sentence in the following way to understand why the singular *professor* should be used:

> Entrance exams for associate-professor posts will begin on Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20post%20of%20assistant%2Cthe%20posts%20of%20assistant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20post%20of%20assistant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20posts%20of%20assistant%3B%2Cc0), you will see that **the post of** is very much more common than **the posts of**. This is probably largely because most references to a post are for a single position, either because there is only one person with a particular job title or because there are many people with the same job title but generally only one position is vacant at any time.

That said, we can also use **the post of** to refer to a particular type or class of position, which is uncountable, even when many people can fill that post. Here is a typical example:

> We recommend that **the post of** Gardener be graded on Scale G 1, 2 and Head Gardener on Scale G 3. - *[Report of the Grading Team on the Grading of Posts in the Public Services of the Federation of Nigeria, April 1966](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=obRmp4bLF24C&q=%22the%20post%20of%20gardener%22&dq=%22the%20post%20of%20gardener%22&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA1-Ha5-ffAhUITo8KHf9dBHYQ6AEIMDAB)*

In the sentence that you quote, it is perfectly acceptable to say **the post of**, as a class description,  even if there are many positions of associate professor available:

> Entrance exams for the post of associate professor will begin on Tuesday

Most native English speakers would prefer to use the **the post of** in this way, though I think that very few would be able to explain this preference.

You are quite correct that using the plural **posts** is not wrong, though the singular is much more widely used.